# Unit test Yii Behaviors

Tags: php, unit-testing, yii

I'm looking for a way to unit test Yii behaviors based on CActiveRecordBehavior.

As the behaviors concerned can be used with many models, I want to test them independently of any model, but I can't work out how to do it.

The Yii source gives a unit test of the CTimestampBehavior using a database table that's made especially for the test. I have a lot of behaviors to test and don't want to have to create a table for each one - can anyone suggest a better strategy for testing behaviors without dependency on a specific model or table? Maybe some way to "fake" a CActiveRecord model?

[edit] To clarify - I don't want my test to rely on a specific model or database table being present - I want to test the behavior only. And just to make things even more interesting, the behavior attaches to the onAfterConstruct event, so it would need to be applied to the fake model before construct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what you want to test.

I usually implement them like this:

```
private $_oBehavior
private $_oObject;
private $_oEvent

$this->_oObject   = Object::model()->findByPk(n1);
$this->_oEvent    = new CModelEvent($this->oJob);
$this->_oBehavior = new TestBehavior;
$this->_oBehavior->attach($this->_oEvent->sender);

$this->_oBehavior->afterSave($this->_oEvent);
// asserts
```

This way you can test all stuff that needs a model by instantiating it like an event. All stuff that don't need a model can also be tested like this.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that would require a model object of some kind. That's kinda the point of the question, I don't want testing my behavior to be reliant on me not changing what models and tables are available. In your example I need to work out what "Object" is

Comment: What you can do is create a mocking Object class which extends from CModel. That way you won't need any table changes whatsoever